# Running a JavaFx Jar on Windows 2012 Server

Tags: windows, netbeans, javafx-2, windows-server-2012

I have a JavaFx program that I have built and compiled in NetBeans, all my projects are stored on a Windows 2012 server that has the latest Java 7 version installed on it.

When I remotely log onto the server and attempt to run the jar from directly from its dist folder, the program will open, but do not run. (A small window with two buttons that should start and stop the program but clicking on them does nothing.) A shortcut to the jar on the Desktop of the server has the same effect.

The program however has no issues running on non-server computers via a shortcut.

I have attempted to create a .bat file to run the program and running it gives me the following error list:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

However, I have included all the jars in my .bat that the program needs, as show below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java" -cp "E:\IT Server\Netbeans 
Projects\DataManipulator\build\classes;E:\IT Server\Netbeans Projects\
DataManipulator\dist\lib\opencsv-2.3.jar;E:\IT Server\Netbeans Projects\
DataManipulator\dist\lib\javax.mail-1.5.0_1;E:\IT Server\Netbeans     
Projects\DataManipulator\dist\lib\javadbf-0.4.0;E:\IT Server\Netbeans 
Projects\DataManipulator\dist\lib\commons-net-3.3;E:\IT Server\Netbeans 
Projects\DataManipulator\dist\lib\commons-io-2.4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib\jfxrt" ads.DataManipulator 
pause
```

I'm really at a loss as to why I can't get my program to execute on the server, but can on a regular machine. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .bat classpath, the `jfxrt` entry is included as *folder*, not as *JAR*; it should be `...\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar`. Others seem to have the same problem too, e.g. `commons-io-2.4`, `javax.mail-1.5.0_1` etc.

Also you may want to check the packager tool ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packager.htm)) or relevant Ant tasks ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_tasks.htm)) for the most appropriate and safe packaging of your application.

Comment: That was it and fixing those things helped me uncover the underlying issues (it turned out there was a permissions matter for the server log in as well as a FileNotFound matter both of which were able to be fixed.)